# Request for online reference to Hamilton's "The Ricci Flow on Surfaces"

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Does anyone know of an online source for Richard Hamilton's paper "The Ricci Flow on Surfaces?" I've searched Google for it and it doesn't seem to give any results.

Comment: I'm not really sure if it includes what you are looking for, but there is [this](http://faculty.math.tsinghua.edu.cn/~lma/lectures%5Cricciface2.pdf) short book on Hamilton's work on Ricci flow. There is also [this](http://www.msri.org/realvideo/ln/msri/2003/ricciflow/hamilton/1/index.html) lecture by Hamilton on the Ricci flow, in which (I think) he starts at his early work and goes through Perelman's work. (I am not sure if any of this helps, but Google turned up nothing for the original paper.)

Answer (score 5):

Here is an online link for the [paper.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4iewe90pb8n1ptu/%28Contemporary%20Mathematics%20071%29%20James%20A.%20Isenberg-Mathematics%20and%20General%20Relativity_%20Proceedings-Amer%20Mathematical%20Society%20%28198.pdf?dl=0) Due to copyright reasons the link shall be disabled in a few days. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The article appears in "Mathematics and General Relativity" Edited by James A. Isenberg , Contemporary Mathematics Volume 71 , (1988) , pp 237- 262 .

You might have some luck trying that title in your search.